# Poincare Inequality for Mean-Zero Functions

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, poincare-duality

I'm studying Sobolev spaces these days and came across a property of Poincare Inequality for mean-zero functions that I don't understand;

> $u(x,y)=-u(x,-y) \implies \int_\Omega u=0$ and that Poincare Inequality for zero mean-value functions can be applied

The domain is $\Omega=B(0,1) \subset \Bbb{R^2}$. Can anyone guide me on what I'm missing here?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: How $u(x,y)=-u(x,-y) \implies \int_\Omega u=0$

Comment: Because $\Omega$ is symmetric wrt the $x$ axis. The same argument as for functions $u:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$ with $u(x)=-u(-x)$ so that $\int_{-1}^1 u=0$.

Comment: @daw thank you so much.

Comment: Also for a function to be holder continuous like this 
$|u(x,y)-u(x,0)| \le constant|x-x, y-0| $. Is this correct because if this is then I'm not getting $|y|$ only?